# Automate creation of Test Plan

Tags: testing, jmeter, automated-tests

We're using JMeter to load test our application. Currently, whenever there is a change in the request body and headers, I need to open the JMeter UI, save the test plan, then execute this plan using jmeter command.

Is there any way the test plan modification can happen without the requirement of opening the JMeter UI and modifying it? So that I can directly run the jmeter command with the changes without having to open the UI.

Or is there any other application which facilitates this?

Comment: It depends, what you need to change, give examples

Comment: @user7294900 Hi, as mentioned in the question, I want to change the request body and request header values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can configure JMeter to read the request body from the file using [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function like:

   [image]
2. You can use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) for each value you want to parameterize like:

   [image]

   Once done you will be able to pass the properties via `-J` command-line argument as:

   ```
    jmeter -Jheader.name.1=Content-Type -Jheader.value.1=applicatino/json -Jheader.name.2=Host -Jheader.name.2=example.com etc.
   ```
3. There is [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) which can fetch values from the comma-separated-value files
4. You can pass an arbitrary .properties file (name-value-pair file) to JMeter via `-q` command-line argument and specify your changed values there, the values can be read using the aforementioned `__P() function`

Check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article to learn more about JMeter Functions concept.